# UIcollectionview repeats the last cell many times in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I am trying to implement a chat log controller by filling all the messages that I get from a chatroom chat SDK and fill them into a message array: `var messages =  [Message]()`. Therefore I implemented the following function:

```
func observeMessages() {

    let modelmessage = Message()

    //case of chat inside an Open Channel
    if openChannel != nil {
        SBDOpenChannel.getWithUrl((openChannel?.channelUrl)!) { (channel, error) in
            let previousMessageQuery = channel?.createPreviousMessageListQuery()
            previousMessageQuery?.loadPreviousMessages(withLimit: 100, reverse: false, completionHandler: { (messages, error) in
                for message in messages!{

                    if let usermessage = message as? SBDUserMessage {

                    modelmessage.fromId = usermessage.sender?.nickname
                    //print (modelmessage.fromId)
                    modelmessage.text = usermessage.message!
                    modelmessage.timestamp = usermessage.createdAt
                    self.messages.append(modelmessage)
                    print ("////")
                        for element in self.messages {
                            print(element.text)
                        }

                    }

                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                })


            })


        }
    }

    //Case of a 1 on 1 chat
    else {

    }

}
```

and the following functions responsible for filling the UICollectionView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView?.register(ChatMessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    setupInputComponents()
}



override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell


    let message = self.messages[indexPath.item]

    cell.textView.text = message.text

    return cell
}
```

When I try to print the `messages` array while it is getting filled I realised  it is filled by the element currently indexed times the number in the index so I get for example:

```
////
Optional("Aaa")
////
Optional("Hello")
Optional("Hello")
////
Optional("Hello World")
Optional("Hello World")
Optional("Hello World")

.
.
.
//Until I complete 16 iterations so I get

////
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
Optional("Bye")
```

Comment: The line `print (self.messages)` prints the messages **before** the array is getting filled. The completion handler is executed much later.

Comment: I modified the question to show the print statement in both places. Could you please check again please?

Comment: If the new received messages are supposed to replace the previous messages you have to call `self.messages.removeAll()` at the beginning of the completion handler

Comment: @vadian, did that same problem remains.

Comment: @vadian Would you please check again, I discovered some new behaviour.

Comment: clear sel.messages.removeAll() before the first for loop and your print statement is in wrong place

Comment: Doesn't seem to work @JaydeepVyas

Comment: for element in self.messages {
                            print(element.text)
                        } it is wrong instead use print(modulmessage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i feel the place of reloading your collection view cells is wrong.
Just comment "self.collectionView?.reloadData()" and see if it changes something.

UPDATE:

Since you have written this "let modelmessage = Message()" outside your completion handler, all the values refer to the same instance hence is overwritten each time. Just move this inside the completion handler and your issue will be resolved. Cheers

Comment: Since you have written this "let modelmessage = Message()" outside your completion handler, all the values refer to the same instance hence is overwritten each time. Just move this inside the  completion handler and your issue will be resolved. Cheers